# <Android> google map not loading fresh tiles when zoomed in

Tags: java, android, google-maps

my question is something I've been trying to figure out for days.
I've seen alot of related questions and tried every suggested solution to no avail.

My issue is that in my app, the map's tiles are only loading for the maximum zoomed out state.
So my map is loading, I highly doubt its an issue with my SDK, permissions, the google key, the map fragment, or the availability of providers.

If I try the maps app on my device, it works fine, and loads the tiles at any zoom level, in my app however, the map is fine when fully zoomed out, but as I start zooming in, the map becomes low res, ie its not loading new tiles (i dont really know how this works..) at around 15 zoom level, the map just becomes the gray squares without any tiles.

I place some markers on the map, and they work fine, my position gets updated etc
The only thing is that tiles do not load beyond the max zoomed out level.

Let me know what you think people, thanks in advance :)

Comment: could you show what permissions you have provided in you manifest file?

Comment: So, you have found the problem... then provide an answer to yourself and accept it.

Comment: gah, I need to wait 8 hours :(
thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I noticed the problem, Its my internet, last time I tried this, I tried it with both network and wifi, and both times it didnt load the tiles, Im guessing the network was too slow and there was something wrong with the university wifi I was using, cause today I tried again, and after waiting and losing all my call credit, the tiles slowly loaded through the network...
The only funny part is that on all occasions, the maps app loaded any zoom level, i guess the tiles are already stored for it, but for my personal app, they need to be downloaded?...